# Attach file using ajax button in Yii

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, yii

I need to upload file  using ajax button. File upload is working well when I use a simple CHTML button in yii with the same controller action. But using ajax button Iam not able to save the uploaded file.

This is my form :

```
    <?php echo CHtml::form('Mes', 'post', array('id' => 'frm', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data')); ?>
    <?php echo CHtml::textArea('Message', '', array('maxlength' => 500, 'id' => 'messagetextarea1', 'rows' => 6, 'cols' => 50)); ?>
<?php echo CHtml::fileField('attach', '', array('size' => 55, 'maxlength' => 55)); ?>
<?php
  // echo CHtml::button('save',array('submit'=>'/mailbox/message/save'));   -   simple button working fine

      echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton('Send', CHtml::normalizeUrl(array('/mailbox/message/save', 'render' => true)), array(
                                        'dataType' => 'json',
                                        'type' => 'post',

                                            ));
                                            ?>
<?php echo CHtml::endForm(); ?>
```

Controller :

```
if (isset($_POST['Message']))
    {
       $model = new Message;
        //echo $_POST['Message'];
        //echo $_POST['Text'];
         $model->attachments = CUploadedFile::getInstanceByName('attach', 'attachments');
        Yii::app()->user->setState('attachmnt',$model->attachments);
        $uploadfile = $model->attachments;
        if ($uploadfile->saveAs(dirname(Yii::app()->basePath) . '/images/' . $uploadfile))
        {
            echo "saved";
        }
        $model->save();
}
```

How to save attachment using ajax ?

Comment: then sibmit form via ajax.

Comment: @kumar_v how to do it ?

Comment: refer this : http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/8219-solved-ajax-form-submission/

Answer (score 1):

as far as i know  Yii ajax button does not support file upload , if you want ajax file upload you can use "jquery file upload" http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/xupload